# Ubuntu Software hide reviews and rating

Tags: software-center

Is it possible to hide the Ubuntu Software reviews and star ratings because they are mostly written by trolls and have very low scores anyhow?

Comment: You know this how?

Comment: @David I'll add some screenshots soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to hide the Ubuntu Software reviews and star ratings, unless you would edit the source code and recompile the application.